# What would keep custom fields from rendering in the frontend on Joomla 4

Tags: custom-field, joomla-4.x, joomla-4

When using the shortcode (example `{field34}`) for a field in the Article editor text area the field content is not showing on the front end.

I entered the fields manually and also used the dropdown and selected the field from the list.

Is there a setting that designates when field short codes should be rendered or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed there might be a couple of reasons for that. But the main one I see in your case is that you might have not enable the content plugin for fields
plg_content_fields. Here is a screenshot:

[image: The content plugin for fields to render the smart tags related to fields in an article]

Comment: this is enabled for me